# How to begin debugging POST and GET requests in Django and Python Shell

Tags: html, django, postgresql, post, get

I have written the following code.
The issue that I am having is that the database is not being updated and a new record is not being made. I am assuming that the way I am retrieving my POST are incorrect but that's why I am asking where do I begin to debug? I have created template variables for quantity,action,building, and test. When I try to call them in the html {{ test }} for example nothing ever shows up even the one that is hardcoded. I used firebug and the form is indeed posting the values that should be posted.
the form consists of two drop down menus one for action and one for building. A numerical input quantity, a text box and a submit button. If anyone can offer me some advice it would be appreciated. I really don't understand why the hardcoded one doesn't show up 
If you need any more information please let me know.

```
def update(request,Type_slug, slug, id):
    error = False
    Slug = slug
    ID = id
    Type = Type_slug
    test = 'test'
    quantity = request.POST['Qty']
    action = request.POST['Action']
    building = request.POST['Building']
    comments = request.POST['Comments']
    if Type == 'Chemicals':
       item = Chemicals.objects.filter(S_field=Slug, id= ID)
       New_Record = ChemicalRecord(Name=item.Name,Barcode=item.Barcode,Cost=item.Cost,Action=action,Building=building)
       if building == 'Marcus':
           building_two = 'Pettit'
       elif building =='Pettit':
           building_two ='Marcus'
       Record_one = ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Barcode=New_Record.Barcode).filter(Building=New_Record.Building)
       if Record_one:
           Record_one = ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Barcode=New_Record.Barcode).filter(Building=New_Record.Building).latest('id')
           New_Record.On_hand = Record_one.On_hand
       else:
           New_Record.On_hand = 0
       if action == 'Receiving':
           New_Record.On_hand = New_Record.On_hand+quantity
       elif action == 'Removing':
           New_Record.On_hand = New_Record.On_hand-quantity
           Record_two = ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Barcode=New_Record.Barcode).filter(Building=building_two)
       if Record_two:
           Record_two = ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Barcode=New_Record.Barcode).filter(Building=building_two).latest('id')
           Record_two_qty = Record_two.On_hand
       else:
           Record_two_qty = 0
       New_qty = New_Record.On_hand+Record_two_qty
       Chemicals.objects.filter(Barcode=obj.Barcode).update(On_hand=New_qty)
       New_Record.save()
```

Comment: you can use [`import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. Apparently in never enters that method because there is another method that it is entering instead so none of the code ever gets executed. How do I make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [import pdb;pdb.set_trace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) for debugging.

Comment: Also here is a link that give a tutorial about how to use it.
https://mike.tig.as/blog/2010/09/14/pdb/